# Is there a way to use value from CUST_DDA port as input port for lookup?

Tags: informatica

I'm trying to use a Lookup transformation to extract ACCT_ID from `ACCT` table based on the port `CUST_DDA` which is an output port from an expression.
I'm using an sqloverride as below. The initial lookup condition :

```
SUBSTR_ACCT_ID = IN_CUST_DDA
```

Override:

```
SELECT 
ACCT.ACCT_ID as ACCT_ID, 
ACCT.ALT_ACCT_ID as ALT_ACCT_ID, 
substr(acct.acct_id,-1*(length(IN_CUST_DDA))) as SUBSTR_ACCT_ID 
FROM ACCT 
WHERE ACCT.ALT_ACCT_ID LIKE '%'||TO_CHAR(IN_CUST_DDA) 
AND ACCT.ACCT_ID LIKE '%'||TO_CHAR(IN_CUST_DDA)
```

The above sql override is failing due to the error : ORA-00904: "IN_CUST_DDA": invalid identifier

Is there a way to use the value from CUST_DDA port as an input port for the lookup. CUST_DDA is not a field that belongs to the ACCT table. Is there a way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the override I can see that you are trying to convert **IN_CUST_DDA** into CHAR, also at the same time your using **IN_CUST_DDA** in the length.

Might be the length function causing the issue, because length function can be used along with a string.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use CUST_DDA(from source) in your lookup override. You need to join the lookup table with source with a common field in the override.

You cant use the port in the way you mentioned. When you run the workflow informatica integration service will run the lookup override query in the database and get the data into the cache file (that is the reason you are receiving the error  "IN_CUST_DDA": invalid identifier.) . Once the cache file is ready it will apply the conditions and then get the output for you.

Let me know if you are not clear on this

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to configure your lookup as non-cached, so the query will be executed for each input row. Note, that this degrades performance a lot.
Next, you need to use a bit different syntax, enclosing the input port in question marks. Here's an [example](http://powercenternotes.blogspot.se/2017/05/using-lookup-input-ports-in-sql.html). In your case it should be something like (this might need a little adjustment):

```
SELECT 
ACCT.ACCT_ID as ACCT_ID, 
ACCT.ALT_ACCT_ID as ALT_ACCT_ID, 
substr(acct.acct_id,-1*(length(?IN_CUST_DDA?))) as SUBSTR_ACCT_ID 
FROM ACCT 
WHERE ACCT.ALT_ACCT_ID LIKE '%'||TO_CHAR(?IN_CUST_DDA?) 
AND ACCT.ACCT_ID LIKE '%'||TO_CHAR(?IN_CUST_DDA?)
```